# Error when I try install @schematics/update@0.803.2

Tags: angular, npm, package.json, angular-schematics

When I tried to `npm i @schematics/update@0.803.2` I got:

```
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @schematics/update@0.803.2
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

I tried removing `package-log.json` and removed `node_modules`. I need to install this package because when it invokes the command `npm install — save-dev @angular/cli@latest` I have a message that this dependency is missing. My main goal is to update Angular 5.2 to Angular 8.